# How do I conditionally pass the DocumentNode parameter to a useLazyQuery hook depending on the state of my application?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am trying to call different type of queries using the useLazyQuery hook depending on certain state changes in my application. Is there a way to initialize useLazyQuery() without a DocumentNode and later pass the DocumentNode parameter and call the query?

To further explain here is my code explaining what I wish to achieve.

```
export const Interactions: React.FC<interactionsProps> = ({}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(InteractionListReducer, null);
  const { data: usersData } = useUsersQuery();
  const { data: filters } = useGet_FiltersQuery();

 const  [getInteractions,{data: interactionData, refetch: refetchInteraction, fetchMore}] = useLazyQuery()
// useLazyQuery REQUIRES A DOCUMENTNODE (QUERY AS PARAMETER) BUT I DO NOT KNOW THE TYPE OF QUERY YET
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state?.filterSelected?.id) {
      //THIS RETURNS THE DOCUMENT NODE BASED ON THE FILTER SELECTED
      const queryNode = getInteractionsQueryType(state.filterSelected.system); 


      //THEN HERE I WANT TO CALL THE HOOK WITH THE DOCUMENTNODE THAT I JUST OBTAINED 
       getInteractions({query: queryNode  })

    }
  }, [state?.filterSelected?.id]);
```

Is it possible to achieve this using useLazyQuery hook? If not is there an alternative to achieve this kind of querying depending on the state of application?

Comment: You can't conditionally run a hook. Why not just run a default query?

Comment: What do you mean by default query? I am using this lazy hook to fetch my data conditionally depending on my application state.

Comment: I mean start with at least a query that returns something - even if you don't do anything with the result (ex: fetch the server time). Then drop in other queries based on state.

Comment: I thought about this but I was hoping that there is a more elegant way to this rather than sending a pointless query when it's not needed.

Comment: You can do a "cache-only" query and avoid a network request. OR - you can not even render this component until your application state has a useful query to run. I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: ps. It's best to avoid running multiple queries in a single component (`useUsersQuery` and `useGet_FiltersQuery`. You can combine multiple gql queries into a single request.

Comment: I see, may I know the reason for this? Combining everything into a single request seems counter intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

One of the rules of hooks is that the number of hooks run inside a component should not change, i.e. don't conditionally run a hook.

With that in mind:

1. Don't render your component until there's a query to be run:

```
{readyForInteractions ? <Interactions /> : null }
```

2. Use whatever query you want in `useLazyQuery`, even one that varies based on state

And as a further optimization:

3. Combine your two queries into one, ex:

```
query interactions {
  useUsers {
    field1
    field2
  }
  useGetFilters {
    fieldA
    fieldB
  }
}
```

This will make dealing with `loading` and `error` states much simpler while also eliminating a redundant network request.

4. Finally, if your queries are only changing based on their parameters, use query variables to run them instead of injecting variables straight into the query text - as it appears you may be doing with `getInteractionsQueryType(state.filterSelected.system)`